# Can we apply IVT to solve this?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, periodic-functions

Let $f:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and periodic (meaning that $f(2\pi) = f(0)$). Show that there exists an $x ∈ [0, π]$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\pi)$. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT : Let $g :  [0,\pi]$ be defined by $g(x) = f(x+\pi) - f(x)$.

- Is $g$ continuous? (Must be)
- What is the relationship between $g(0)$ and $g(\pi)$?
- If $g(x) = 0$ for some $x$, what does that imply about $f$?

---

Question : Can we find another constant $c$ not $\pi$ or $2 \pi$ such that $f(x+c) = f(x)$ must occur for some $x$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f(0)=f(\pi)$ then we're done, so suppose otherwise.

Without loss of generality, this gives $f(0)-f(0+\pi)>0$. Then we have $f(\pi)-f(0)<0$, but we know that $f(0)=f(2\pi)=f(\pi+\pi)$, so we get $f(\pi)-f(\pi+\pi)<0$. Do you see how to proceed by considering $f(x)-f(x+\pi)$ with IVT?